Data Labels on Relationship Map - SPSS Relationship Map
I have created a Relationship Map on SPSS and need to display all the data labels of the options selected (the option itself and the number of choices). I cannot find a solution since everything found (not so many options) online do not seem to work.
RelationshipMap
Tried the options in official IBM page for adding data labels but this seems to be applicable for charts and not the relationship map: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/saas?topic=chart-data-labels
